# Question about star-finite collection in general topology

Tags: general-topology

According to this [link](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Star-finite_collection) (which is related to the definition of star-finite collection),

> A **star-finite collection** of subsets of a set is a collection of subsets such that every member of the collection intersects only finitely many members.

Again, in the "weaker condition" section, they claim that

> If we have a start-finite *open* collection (in other words, a star-finite collection comprising of open sets), then it is a locally finite collection.

If the given star-finite open collection, say $\mathcal U$, is a covering of the whole space, say $X$, then it is trivially true, because for each $x \in X$, we can find a suitable open set in $\mathcal U$ that contains $x$. But my question is, what about the case when $\mathcal U$ is **not** a cover of $X$? Does above holds for that case too?

Any comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It need not. Let $X$ be a [hedgehog space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedgehog_space) of infinite spininess, obtained by identifying the $0$ points of the disjoint union of infinitely many copies of $[0,1]$, and let $\mathscr{U}$ be the collection of copies of $(0,1]$; then $\mathscr{U}$ is a pairwise disjoint family of open sets, hence certainly star-finite, but every open nbhd of the common $0$ point meets every member of $\mathscr{U}$. The most that we can say in general is that $\mathscr{U}$ is a locally finite cover of its union.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It became clear to me.

Comment: @user20961: You’re welcome!